# MVC Model for webshop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am relatively new to MVC and I am working on making a webshop in MVC.

My current model for displaying products (or shopping cart items):

```
public class ShoppingCartItems
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual string ProductName { get; set; }
    public virtual int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public virtual decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }
    public virtual int AmountAvailable { get; set; }
}
```

Should I add a property here in order to make a connection between a user who has logged in and the products the user chose to add to the shoppingcart or should I take a look at this matter in the controller instead (or make use of both controller and model to relate the two)?

In this example I also make use of a CategoryID which should point to a category class containing the (available) option values of categories. How do I make such a relationship in MVC between classes?

Comment: Take a look at this: [Entity Framework 6 Code First using MVC 5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: "For this tutorial you won't be requiring users to log on or restricting access based on who's logged on." That's the thing, I want to make use of this and learn how to apply this to my MVC project. I'll take a look at the tutorial though as it may has some content that might be of use to my questions regarding entity framework. Thank you for sharing this.

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to do. Do you want to return to the client another object that holds user data?

Comment: You can create a ShoppingCart Obejct which has a User and a List<ShoppingCartItems>

Answer (score 0):

To identify user who is logged you could use Membership, Simple Membership, Identity or implement your own authetication. You can read more for example here. http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity. For category problem you can just add property of type Category to your model. Details depend on what ORM you are using.